# Posterior distribution of $\theta$ for density $f(x|\theta) = \theta x^{\theta - 1}$ and prior $Gamma(a,b)$

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I'm having trouble solving the following problem:

> Suppose $x$ is a random variable with distribution $f(x|\theta) = \theta
>  x^{\theta - 1}$, you observe a sample of $x$ with size $n$ and
>   $\theta$ have a prior distribution $Gamma(a,b)$. Find the posterior
>   distribution of $\theta | x$.

**These are my results:**

$p(\theta|x) \propto p(X_1,...,X_{n}|\theta)p(\theta) \propto \theta^{a-1}e^{-b\theta}\theta^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{\theta - 1}
=\theta^{n+a-1}e^{-b\theta}\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{\theta - 1} $

**My doubt is:**

How does the last equation from right become a $Gamma(n+a,b \sum^{n}_{i=1}\log x_{i})$?

Comment: The second parameter of the gamma distribution should be $b-\sum\log x_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply note that
$$\theta^{n+a-1}e^{-b\theta}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{\theta-1} = \theta^{n+a-1}e^{-b\theta}\exp\left(\ln\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{\theta-1}\right)\right)= \theta^{n+a-1}\exp\left(-b\theta+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\ln(x_{i}^{\theta-1})\right)\propto \theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\theta\beta}$$
with
$$
\alpha=a+n,\qquad\beta=b-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ln(x_{i}).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Tip: write
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n} ...
$$
as
$$
\exp \log \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} ... \right).
$$
And remember
$$\log \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} ... \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(...)$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does provide the answer if the author is willing to give in some effort on his own. And I believe he is, since he provided his partial results.